# How can I add the header background image? - MeteorJS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, bootstrap-4

I am using [this](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/) template from bootstrap in my Meteor project.

The problem is that the header background image doesn't appear.

The code that should set up the header background is located inside `css/agency.css` folder as follows:

```css
header.masthead {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("../img/header-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and here is the header HTML script:

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro-text">
      <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To Our Studio!</div>
      <div class="intro-heading text-uppercase">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Tell Me More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

What I did is, I created a folder called `public` in my root directory and copied all the images there.

Then I changed the `background-image: url("../img/header-bg.jpg");` to `background-image: url("header-bg.jpg");` then `background-image: url("../../public/header-bg.jpg");` but both attempts didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: then it should be `background-image: url("../public/header-bg.jpg");` if your css folder is same level as public folder

Comment: @Hareesh sorry, thats what I have tried, my mistake not realizing it, sorry and thank you for helping me noticing it :)

Comment: any error on browser developer console?

Comment: @Hareesh yes, quite few, here is the picture https://ibb.co/cHZKD6 but non of them is caused by agency.css. Do you think the problem might be caused due to the errors on the console?

Comment: no thats bootstrap specific error..

Comment: @Hareesh thats what i thought as well, bootstrap and jquery related errors

Comment: Did you try `/img/header-bg.jpg`? Your `/public` folder should be exposed into web as `/` by Meteor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the bootstrap template, you have to make the same changes you made in `css/agency.css` to `css/agency.min.css` and it should work.

Hope this will help